# Adding Custom Code(View) to DinkToPdf header

Tags: c#, html, dinktopdf

I am building `html` views with `stringbuilder` and using `DinkToPDF` to convert this HTML to a pdf. I have been able to add a header and footer using the following(By creating static `HTML` pages:

```
var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
        {
            PagesCount = true,
            HtmlContent = await _template.Build(data, hostUrl),
            //HeaderSettings = { HtmUrl = hostUrl + "/views/v1/getview?reportName=AcademicTranscript&viewName=test.html&themeName=SchoolTheme_SchoolId", 
            HeaderSettings = { HtmUrl = hostUrl + _swaggerConfig.BasePath + "/views/v1/getview?reportName=AcademicTranscript&viewName=portraitheader.html",
                Line = true, Right = "[page]/[sitepages]", Spacing = 5 },
            FooterSettings = { HtmUrl = hostUrl + _swaggerConfig.BasePath + "/views/v1/getview?reportName=AcademicTranscript&viewName=portraitfooter.html",
                Line = true },
        };
```

This works great, but I need to add a custom `html` view as part of the header, which contains details, such as Name, surname, address etc.

Is there a way of adding a custom built page(meaning Html tags etc. with information from the Database) to the header?

I hope my question makes sense.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at the moment there are 2 ways to setup a document header content in [HeaderSettings](https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/blob/b0546d21641eaef71f6fe0ddfd3998e8502baab7/src/DinkToPdf/Settings/HeaderSettings.cs) in **DinkToPDF**:

1. fill `Left`, `Center`, `Right` properties with a plain text
2. pass a path to a header file in HTML format in `HtmUrl` property

So you can retrieve the needed data from a database, fill an HTML header file with HTML renderer like [this one](https://github.com/stubbleorg/stubble), pass the header file's path to `HeaderSettings.HtmUrl` property, generate your PDF document with DinkToPDF and delete the header file afterwards.

An example for generating HTML files by template can be found [here](https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/generating-dynamic-pdf-reports-from-html-template-using-c-sharp)